# How to access Mustache HTML template from external <script />

Tags: jquery, mustache

I'm using [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) to render different recurring parts of an HTML site. Until now I have every template inside a `<script />` and access its contents through jQuerys `html()` method:

```
<script type="text/html" id="html-script">
    <!-- ... -->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('script[type="text/html"]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    templates[$this.attr('title')] = $this.html();
});
</script>
```

Now I would like to put each template in its own file and include them like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="html-script" src="template.html"></script>
```

This does not work so my question is

1. Why not?
2. How can get this to work?

I read an article about [How to Load Mustache.js Templates From an External File with jQuery](http://www.levihackwith.com/how-to-load-mustache-js-templates-from-an-external-file-with-jquery/) which I could use as a fallback solution but I would really appreciate if I not had to `$.get()` the templates myself.

Answer (score 1):

While the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) is confusingly vague on what the `src`of a `<script>` element can be, it does say that "A resource is a script resource of a given type if that type identifies a scripting language and the resource conforms with the requirements of that language's specification." Practically, this means that a browser will only load javascript, and you cannot interact with an HTML document loaded this way.

I would rethink the way you are trying to solve your problem. This is a solution to asynchronously load template files stolen from the ever helpful [Christophe Conraets](http://coenraets.org/blog/):

```
// Asynchronously load templates located in separate .html files
function loadTemplate (views, callback) {
    var deferreds = [];

    $.each(views, function(index, view) {
        if (window[view]) {
            deferreds.push($.get('tpl/' + view + '.html', function(data) {
                window[view].prototype.template = _.template(data);
            }));
        } else {
            alert(view + " not found");
        }
    });

    $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(callback);
}

loadTemplate(['view', 'view2','view3'], function() {
    // do amazing things...
});
```

[[source](https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar/blob/master/public/js/utils.js#L3)]
(obviously, modify the `tpl` directory to suit your needs)

You could also do this with something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) (my preffered method).

Comment: Could you explain how the magic happens between `deferreds.push()` and `// do amazing things`? :) . . . I mean, where's the view object?

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the jQuery holdReady method to add a delay to the onReady-event. Note, that the jquery-script must be included before the resource loading script.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="mustache.min.js"></script>

<script id="template1" type="x-tmpl-mustache" src="template1.html"></script>
<script id="template2" type="x-tmpl-mustache" src="template2.html"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('script[type="x-tmpl-mustache"]').each(function(idx, templateSource) {
    $.holdReady(true);
    $.get(templateSource.src, function(template) {
        templateSource.text = template;
        $.holdReady(false);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    Console.log("All templates loaded.");
});
</script>
```